# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

**Project [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg2w7.png)**

**Console**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c899f09' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c899f09': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)     
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)     
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)    
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)   
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)  
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)  
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)   
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)  
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)     
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)    
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)    
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)     
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c899f09' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c899f09': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)     
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)    
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)     
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)   
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)    
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)     ... 26 more
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/security-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- filter to use spring security, be sure to use suggested name "springSecurityFilterchain"-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.internbridge" />  


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean> 

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**spring-context.xml**

```
<http use-expressions="true">    
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/><!-- to check all url wheather user is authenticated or not  -->
    <form-login/><!-- bulid in login form -->
    <logout logout-url="/inde" logout-success-url="/index"/>
</http>     

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="gopal" password="143" authorities="Admin,User"/>
            <user name="naik" password="123" authorities="User"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>        
    <mapping class="com.internbridge.model.Student" />
</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your stack trace, your problem is the following:

```
[org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]:
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V
```

From your question, there is no evidence of the version of the libraries you are using but the method `setCaseSensitive()` for the `AntPathMatcher` exists only for `spring-core` `4.2.x` version or above.

Comment: i'm using  for spring-4.1.5 and for springSecurity-4.2.3

Comment: yes, i updated SpringCore to 4.3.12, this made my day

Comment: @GopalNaikGuguloth Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please remember to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @GopalNaikGuguloth Here it’s explained [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

```
<http use-expressions="true">
```

Replace it with the following:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
```